Efficient computation of a fourier product
Problem:
Consider $3$ square matrices $A$, $B$, and $W$ having the same shape.
I would like to compute the function :
$$f : \omega \mapsto \sum\limits_{k,l,m,n}W[k, m] A[m, l] W[l, n] B[n, k] e^{i(k-l)\omega} e^{i(n-m)\omega},$$
where $i$ denotes the imaginary unit and $A[k,l]$ denotes the entry of $A$ at the $k$-th row and $l$-th column.
Question:
Is it possible to precompute some matrices in order to speed up the evaluation of $f$?
Context:
I have to compute the value of $f$ at a great number of points.
I would like to exploit the Fourier structure of the sum. Maybe the Fourier transform of the matrices can help?
